# How to import stored procedure using code first ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I want to import a stored procedure using EF code-first, the code is created from SQL Server. I tried to check the articles posted but I seem not to find something I understand so far. The SQL statement below is 3 tables joining, so if I can get an example of how I could work around it using the sample code below.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InvoiceReport]
AS
    SELECT 
        Ordering.order_id,
        Ordering.CustomerId,
        Ordering.invoice_number,
        Ordering.date_order_placed, 
        Customer.FirstName, 
        Customer.LastName, 
        Customer.EmailId, 
        Invoice_Line_Items.item, 
        Invoice_Line_Items.department, 
        Invoice_Line_Items.service, 
        Invoice_Line_Items.gender, 
        Invoice_Line_Items.quantity, 
        Invoice_Line_Items.price, 
        Invoice_Line_Items.pick_up_address, 
        Invoice_Line_Items.pick_up_date, 
        Invoice_Line_Items.pick_up_time, 
        Invoice_Line_Items.drop_off_address, 
        Invoice_Line_Items.drop_off_date, 
        Invoice_Line_Items.drop_off_time 
    FROM 
        Ordering 
    JOIN
        Customer ON Ordering.CustId = Customer.CustId
    JOIN
        Invoice_Line_Items ON Customer.CustId = Invoice_Line_Items.CustId

RETURN 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use stored procedures in the following way:

- add a EF code first migration (https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx)
- add the stored procedure to your migration through `Sql()`
- configure the stored procedure with the model builder or in your entity
- use it in your code :-)

Example migration:

```
public partial class yourmigration: DbMigration
{
    protected override void Up()
    {
        Sql("CREATE PROCEDURE SQL HERE");
    }

    //dont forget the down.
}
```

For EF 6, here's a good article about it: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/code-first-insert-update-delete-stored-procedure-mapping.aspx

Comment: Can you please provide an example.

Comment: Check out this link: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/code-first-insert-update-delete-stored-procedure-mapping.aspx

Comment: The **MigrationBuilder** uses this library **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational** and I am using ASP.NET MVC 4. So it does not support. So any alternative that I can use? @Stefan

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry my bad... I have updated the answer, minor change; and I added an article.

Comment: Do you have the article online? If you do please share the link

Comment: It's in the links in the answer